# onmouseup event not firing

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have a document that contains an IFrame (all source items are from the same domain), when I attach the onmouseup event to a div in my IFrame it will fire when my mouse is up, no matter if I am still on the element with my cursor.

But if I leave the IFrame still holding my mouse down and then release, the event is not firing.

Is there some way to catch this issue, maybe know when the user it out from the IFrame with is mouse cursor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mouse events are tied to windows and an iframe is considered a window so you won't get that mouseup event fired to the iframe if the cursor is not on the iframe.  What you could do would be to capture the parent frame's mouseup event on the document like so.

```
$(parent.document).mouseup(functionToRun);
```

or without jQuery

```
parent.document.onmouseup = functionToRun;
```

You would put this in the iframed document.

Comment: This only works if the iframe is on the same domain, but you noted that they are.  :)

Comment: What I did at the end is to catch the mouseup event from the parent as you suggested and then dispatch a mouseup event from the element in the correct IFrame